Help explain the motivation behind this solution: $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}: |z_1 -4i| = 2|z_2 + i|$ and $|z_1 + 4z_2| = 4. \min\{ |z_1 + z_2|\} = ?$

Consider two complex numbers $z_1$, $z_2$ such that $|z_1 -4i| = 2|z_2 + i|$ and $|z_1 + 4z_2| = 4$. What is the smallest value of $T = |z_1 + z_2|?$

Solution:
Let $w_1 = z_1 - 4i$ and $w_2 = 2z_2 + 2i \implies |w_1| = |w_2|$
$|z_1 + 4z_2| = 4 \implies |(w_1 + 4i) + 4\frac{w_2 - 2i}{2}| = |w_1 + 2w_2| = 4$
Let $A$ and $B$ be the points representing $w_1$ and $w_2,$ respectively, on the complex plane $Oxy$.
Then $|\vec{OA} + 2\vec{OB}| = 4 \implies OA^2 + 4OB^2 + 4\vec{OA}.\vec{OB} = 16 \implies 5OA^2 + 4\vec{OA}.\vec{OB} = 16$
$T = |z_1 + z_2| = |w_1 + 4i + \frac{w_2 - 2i}{2}| = |w_1 + \frac{w_2}{2} + 3i| \geq ||\vec{OA} + \frac{\vec{OB}}{2}| - 3|$
We have $|\vec{OA} + \frac{\vec{OB}}{2}|^2  = OA^2 + \frac{OB^2}{4} + \vec{OA}\vec{OB} = \frac54OA^2 + \vec{OA}.\vec{OB} = \frac14(5OA^2 + 4\vec{OA}.\vec{OB}) = 4$
$\implies |\vec{OA} + \frac{\vec{OB}}{2}| = 2 \implies T \geq 1$

I really hope someone could explain the motivation behind this solution. It just seems to go on and...end up correct without much explanation. For example, how can we be sure that equality occurs in the triangle inequality?

Hi again :) Can you tell me which exact step are you finding difficult to understand? Is it the inequality related to $T$?

What do you mean by "equality occurs in the triangle inequality"?

@Gwen thanks for coming by again! I struggled to see how to know that this path is productive in the first place. As I once mentioned, this is a multiple-choice question with only a few minutes to solve, and I've solved enough to know how big of the bag of tricks involved for these questions. Looking at the solution, it doesn't look very clear to me that setting $w_1$ and $w_2$ as they are will allow one result to be proportional to another.

I've solved other questions where extra variables are set in various ways but enough motivation was provided. This setup seems to be one that one settles after some trial and error, which does not seem very efficient given the time constraints. I supposed there is stronger motivation somewhere that I missed.

Also, one has to check if equality does occur, which appears to be some time-consuming work as this check doesn't look as simple as the last one I asked.

@user170231 Hi, I was referring to the equality in the triangle inequality, $|A + B| \geq ||A| - |B||.$ Equality (hence the said minimum) only occurs if $A = - kB$ for some non-negative $k$ It doesn't appear obvious that such a $k$ exists with all the constraints of the problem.

The triangle inequality says $T\ge|\cdots|$; that's it, the RHS is your minimum. I'm still not sure I follow, how the inequality becomes an equality?

@user170231 Sorry but I'm struggling to see your confusion. Isn't there an equality sign (=) in this particular inequality? The solution says $T \geq 1,$ which implies that conditions exist for $T$ to equal to $1.$ What I was saying is it's not apparent that this is the case.

Here is a computer-based solution done with Mathematica 14.0;
z1 = a + I*b; z2 = x + I*y;
Minimize[ComplexExpand[{Abs[z1 + z2]^2, 
Abs[z1 - 4*I]^2 == 4*Abs[z2 + I]^2 && Abs[z1 + 4 z2]^2 == 16}],{x, y, a, b}]//FullSimplify


{1,{x->-(21/16),y->-(1/3)-Sqrt[127]/48,a->21/16,b->1/48 (64+Sqrt[127])}}


Thanks! It looks like the original solution is correct. I'm still struggling though to see the motivation behind the original solution :'(
